# Windows 8 WebView navigating on a link crashes

Tags: webview, windows-runtime

I have placed WebView on my page:

```
<WebView x:Name="wv1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

And in my C# i do this:

```
this.wv1.NavigateToString("<p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'>" + "ArticleTitleDemo" + "This is some text blablabla" + "<a>www.google.com<a/>");
```

**And when i click on a hyperlink application in an emulator dies without any error!**
On local machine - all works fine.

**Is this just an emulator bug? Or this will occur on a real device also? How to fix it?**

Comment: What's a "real device"? Your local machine is a "real device", as it's running Win8. Are you sure there's not an unhandled exception occurring?

Comment: Real Device is a tablet. Because on emulator it fail with something like - "Do you want do debug?" but VS doesn't catch it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This made me think of a very annoying problem with Internet Explorer Mobile for Windows Phone 8. If you don't write http:// it can't navigate to a page when using an IP-address. It just gives a mysterious 'Nope- no-can-do'-message.

Anyway, the exception is a JavaScript exception I believe - strange enough. And what you probably see is:

[image]

When running the app on the computer instead of the simulator, there is even this afterwards:

[image]

Try adding http://

```
this.wv1.NavigateToString("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link text</a>");
```

And make sure you close the tags properly in the markup. Hope this helps.